# I can't change the title and the meta description on my wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

here is my site: escapebollaert.com

It is a site made on wordpress, my site is finished and I will want the referenced. I installed the Rank Math SEO plugin. But the problem is, when I modify the title and meta description with the Rank Math SEO plugin, and I do a search on google, the title and meta description do not appear? do you have a solution so that i can change the tittle and meta description of my site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same thing few days back with one of my sites and it took google about 2 days to update it. But you need to know that in some (rare) cases, google will choose what they consider is the best thing to display on their search engine and you will have nothing to do about it. The only thing you can do (in my opinion) is to make sur the title of the page should be the same as the  of your article.

Comment: Okay okay very well, I note the advice. Thank you for your clear answer. Thank you I am reassured.

Answer (score 0):

How long are you waiting?  It takes time for google to scrape your site and store what it wants to display to the searches.

Comment: Since this morning, I started referencing. But at the beginning he didn't show me this title there, it can't come from bad programming ?

Comment: As John says, it can take days or even weeks for search engines to update the data they have on your website. You'll have to wait a bit, Juliette.

Comment: Okay very well, I understand, it's reassuring if I only have to wait.